# How can I make pixel reading and writing functions more efficient in MIPS?

Tags: image-processing, assembly, mips, bmp, mars-simulator

The following MIPS procedures are meant to read and write pixels from a BMP image loaded in the memory.

```
.eqv BMP_FILE_SIZE 90122
.eqv BYTES_PER_ROW 1800

put_pixel:
#description: 
#   sets the color of specified pixel
#arguments:
#   $a0 - x coordinate
#   $a1 - y coordinate - (0,0) - bottom left corner
#   $a2 - 0RGB - pixel color
#return value: none

    sub $sp, $sp, 4     #push $ra to the stack
    sw $ra,4($sp)

    la $t1, image + 10  #adress of file offset to pixel array
    lw $t2, ($t1)       #file offset to pixel array in $t2
    la $t1, image       #adress of bitmap
    add $t2, $t1, $t2   #adress of pixel array in $t2

    #pixel address calculation
    mul $t1, $a1, BYTES_PER_ROW #t1= y*BYTES_PER_ROW
    move $t3, $a0       
    sll $a0, $a0, 1
    add $t3, $t3, $a0   #$t3= 3*x
    add $t1, $t1, $t3   #$t1 = 3x + y*BYTES_PER_ROW
    add $t2, $t2, $t1   #pixel address 

    #set new color
    sb $a2,($t2)        #store B
    srl $a2,$a2,8
    sb $a2,1($t2)       #store G
    srl $a2,$a2,8
    sb $a2,2($t2)       #store R

    lw $ra, 4($sp)      #restore (pop) $ra
    add $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra
# 

get_pixel:
#description: 
#   returns color of specified pixel
#arguments:
#   $a0 - x coordinate
#   $a1 - y coordinate - (0,0) - bottom left corner
#return value:
#   $v0 - 0RGB - pixel color

    sub $sp, $sp, 4     #push $ra to the stack
    sw $ra,4($sp)

    la $t1, image + 10  #adress of file offset to pixel array
    lw $t2, ($t1)       #file offset to pixel array in $t2
    la $t1, image       #adress of bitmap
    add $t2, $t1, $t2   #adress of pixel array in $t2

    #pixel address calculation
    mul $t1, $a1, BYTES_PER_ROW #t1= y*BYTES_PER_ROW
    move $t3, $a0       
    sll $a0, $a0, 1
    add $t3, $t3, $a0   #$t3= 3*x
    add $t1, $t1, $t3   #$t1 = 3x + y*BYTES_PER_ROW
    add $t2, $t2, $t1   #pixel address 

    #get color
    lbu $v0,($t2)       #load B
    lbu $t1,1($t2)      #load G
    sll $t1,$t1,8
    or $v0, $v0, $t1
    lbu $t1,2($t2)      #load R
        sll $t1,$t1,16
    or $v0, $v0, $t1

    lw $ra, 4($sp)      #restore (pop) $ra
    add $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra
```

These functions seem to be not much efficient.

How can I make pixel reading and writing functions more efficient in MIPS?

Comment: If you're using these functions in a loop, there is probably a lot of setup overhead that could be moved out of the loop. One thing that often works wonders is to let the C compiler do the low-level optimizations, and only tweak the code after really understanding where the inefficiency is located.

Comment: take advantage of MARS using little-endian to do a word store of all 4 components, if you can, instead of 3x shift + store.  You might have to load + merge the next byte, and that would potentially be an unaligned store, so maybe not worth it unless you're targeting a MIPS with efficient unaligned word stores.  (Which do exist, especially with MIPS32r6).  Are you optimizing for real wall-clock time MARS emulation speed, or for speed in target clocks on a simulated classic 5-stage RISC (without branch delay slots)?  Or some other kind of simulated MIPS?

Comment: GetPixel could make good use of `lwl` and `lwr` unaligned word load instructions, even if it's not worth it to byte-load + merge for unaligned word store.

Comment: `move $t3, $a0` is pointless, use `sll $t3, $a0, 1` or `add $t3, $a0,$a0` instead to create registers holding x and 2*x

Comment: Saving `$ra` on the stack seems pointless since neither of these functions call any other functions internally.